# How do I fix my custom delete query in Spring MVC (using JPARepository and MYSQL)?

Tags: spring, jsp, jpa, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to delete **every row from a table that has a "lastName" column entry that matches a specific "lastName".** But it's not working. Any recommendations on what I need to revise?

In the Model, I have the lastName variable spelled as lastName. In the MYSQL table, I have that column spelled as last_name.

What am I doing wrong (code below)? Help appreciated. Many thanks.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/delete/{lastName}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "lastName") String lastName) {
                
        guestRepo.deleteBooks(lastName);
            
        return "redirect:/create_guest";
    }
```

**JSP Page (for front end UI)**

```
<c:forEach var="people" items="${reserves}">
            
            <th> 
            
  <input type="text" placeholder=${people.lastName}  id="myInput" path = lastName>
   <button> <a href="/delete/ + ${people.lastName}">Button</a>  </button>
   
    
     </th>
    </c:forEach>
```

**Repository**

```
public interface GuestRepository extends JpaRepository<Guests, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("delete from Guests where lastName= :lastName")
    void deleteBooks(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
}
```

Comment: what is the error? do you have an exception? are the guests not deleted?

Comment: @tremendous7 It does not give any error. If I replace lastName with "id", then it works, and what comes up on the console is the same thing that comes up in the console when I do either id or lastName. 

I believe the reason "id" works is because of this in the repository "public interface GuestRepository extends JpaRepository<Guests, Long>". The reason is because the second parameter is Long. I have id as Long data type. I think that's the reason because when I created another column and tested out "in this new column Long data type, erase each row with number 2", and it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: are there any typos in lastName when you invoke the method? At database level are there any Guests with the lastName you are trying to delete?

Comment: No errors in any of those. For one reason or another, when I aim to delete something in the MYSQL database with the Long data type, it will work in that exact format. But if I trying to delete String datatype, it does not work.

Comment: will a select query find by lastName work? can you add an image with values you have in the column lastName and with the value of lastName you are trying to delete?

Comment: yeah I'll get to the image. what would I write in a select query to delete? 

"select * from <table_name> ______________" ?

Comment: select g from Guests g where g.lastName = ?1. i am basically asking if a select query instead of a delete one leads to data being found

Answer (score 0):

Add native query equal to true as below.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value ="delete from Guests where lastName= 
:lastName", nativeQuery = true)
 void deleteBooks(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified it and it is working better, but with issue. How do I parameterize it? I had to switch a few things due to NativeQuery. But now parameterizing is the issue. If I directly put the last name such as 'johnson' after the equal sign, it will delete that row in MYSQL. But if I just have it as ":lastName" and enter a name on front end and submit, it does not work. I think its not receiving param. 

 "Query(value ="delete from <tableName> where last_name= :lastName", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteBooks(@Param("lastName") String lastName);"

Comment: I've partially figured out he issue. When I do it with a String (lastName) data type, it does not delete it in the MYSQL backend. But when I do it with a LONG data type that is a Long in the MYSQL, which I experimented with and replaced the String parameters with, IT WORKS!  When I do either a Long or a String, the EXACCT SAME THING COMES UP IN THE ECLIPSE CONSOLE! So what is the issue here? Why won't string work? Do you know? Thanks!!! :D

Comment: That native query look like fine.I have doubt your Param value when reach to repository. Why you don't try like this deleteByLastName(String last name) no need to write native query.

Comment: i briefly saw that come up suggested when typing it, but somehow it won't come up again. am i just using an outdated version of something? do i need to have a more updated jar is the reason why "Delete by" is not coming up?

Comment: It wouldn't come up automatically. You have to write. follow the this official document https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords